# Python: Lambda and callback functions?

Tags: python, function, lambda, ftp, callback

Ok so basically I have got this code working but I don't know why. I am using ftplib and retrbinary. Here is the snippet:

```
def download(self):

        if not self.f:
            print("Can't download..... Not connected to a host")
            return
        FILE = self.handle_command("download")
        if FILE:
            #try:
            self.f.retrbinary("RETR %s" % FILE, lambda block: self.handle_download(block, FILE), 1024)
            print("Downloaded '%s' to cwd" % FILE)
            #except:
            #   print("Can't download '%s'" % FILE)

    def handle_download(self, block, filename):
        open(filename, 'wb').write(block)
        print(".")
```

My question is: Why in the lambda function in retrbinary do I write 'block'  after lambda (and before the colon), but not 'filename'?

As opposed to `lambda: self.handle_download(block, FILE)`

or ..... `lambda block, filename: self.handle_download(block, FILE)`

Hope this is clear, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to [`ftplib.FTP.retrbinary()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary) (since I'm *guessing* that `self.f` is a `ftplib.FTP`) is a callable that gets passed each block received in turn. Since there is only one argument, and the argument is the block being received, it is inappropriate to use any other function signature and hence any other values required must be pulled from the scope.